# How to get the Header from a request in a API with C#

Tags: c#, api, rest

I'm building one REST API to my business and I need to get the values from the header in the request but I don't know how?

I need to create a filter in the header and validate this.

Someting like this:
**header: filterDate = false/true**

```
public CarrierController(ICarrierAppService appService, ICarrierEAppService EAppService)
        {
            _appService = appService;
            _EAppService = EAppService;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create or update a carrier
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="messageUniqueId">Message Id from external system </param>
        /// <param name="carrierDto">Carrier to create</param>
        /// <returns>Carrier created or updated</returns>
        [HttpPost]
        [ProducesResponseType (typeof (CarrierDto), 200)]
        [ProducesResponseType (typeof (ErrorResponse), 400)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post (bool isBusinessE, string messageUniqueId, [FromBody] CarrierDto carrierDto) {

                carrierDto = await _EAppService.UpsertCarrierAsync (carrierDto);
                return CreateResponseOnPost (carrierDto, _name);

        }
```

Please help me to level up:'/ I'm only a little noob :'/

Comment: The DDD architecture doesn't really have anything to do with getting a header from a request.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET MVC Core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your method named `Post`, you can get to the headers of the request by using `Request.Headers` dictionary object. For example: `Request.Headers["filterDate"]`